# For how long is a UK invitation/sponsorship letter valid?

Tags: visas, uk, invitation-letters

Can I send the invitation/sponsorship letter today, knowing that my friend is going to **apply** for the visa after two months? Would the invitation letter be still valid, specially the bank statements? Is it going to increase the chances of rejection?

It's for an UK standard visitor visa, however I would appreciate any similar case or relevant information.

**Update #1**

Potentially I'm relocating in the next month, therefore there will be a lot of extra/unplanned costs. That's why I prefer to send the documents right now.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't send it closer to when your friend is applying?  Because bank balances can change quickly, a two month old statement might not hold as much value.

Comment: @Tom I have updated the question.

Comment: Your edit is the exact reason embassies like current statements, because old ones might not indicate available funds.

Comment: After your relocation, will you still be financially able to support your friend's visit? If yes, then why not send the documents later? If no, then how are you actually going to support him/her?

Comment: @DJClayworth I will be able to support her, but I rather show more in my bank statement. but I have already sent the statement and she is going to apply sooner than original plan.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I send the invitation/sponsorship letter today, knowing that my friend is going to apply for the visa after two months?

Yes (on the basis I know no requirement otherwise).

> Would the invitation letter be still valid, specially the bank statements?

As above.

> Is it going to increase the chances of rejection?

Yes, but can't be proven.

> there will be a lot of extra/unplanned costs

So be it, explain what these are (presumably you will have convincing back-up for their exceptional nature). See [**What Is the Purpose of Bank Statements?**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/4995). This may be a (rare) case for providing more than the minimum information required (that is, *both* the statements you would like to show *and* the more recent ones).

*Second thoughts:*

An 'open' invitation letter would not be as convincing as one that is specific. That is, *Mahdi is required to attend meetings* won't be as effective as say *Mahdi is required to attend meetings in weeks 35 and 36 with our Technical Director, Sales Management and others in connection with our expansion plans for our Sudanese subsidiary*. In the latter case, the invitation letter *would* cease to be valid after `week 36`.

Comment: If you don't mind me saying so, this answer doesn't sound very convincing...

Comment: Ok, I would award you a solid +0.5 but there are no half votes here. I'll find another of your answers and give that a +1 :)